# how to give expanded height to listview while it is used inside single child scrollview in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]
Here is a demo where I have taken some container, textfield and listview builder,

I have wrapped all in SingleChildScrollView to avoid pixel error while opening keypad,

Here I want to give possible height to listview ,depend on item count and spacer between listview and save button

Here is my code:

```
  List<String> paybylist=[
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G',
    'H','I','J','K','L','M','N',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(child: Text('Container1')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            //color: Colors.green,
            child: Center(
              child: CustomTextField(),
            ),
          ),
          Text('Select Payment Mode'),
          Container(
            height: 400,//height should be based on available space
            color: Colors.grey,
            child:ListView.builder(
                itemCount: paybylist.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(paybylist[index]),
                  );
                }) ,
          ),

             //want to add available space between listview and save button

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: (){},child: Center(child: Text('Save')),),
          )

        ],),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add `Expanded` inside the `Scrollable` Widget in flutter,

---

To fill the available gap, place the `save` button in `bottomNavigationBar`

So now the `ListView` doesn't need fixed height of 400 and it can span to have the full height. *In fact it will span only the height of children*

---

Make sure you add `shrinkWrap :true` and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` inside the `ListView.builder()`

##### Your present structure

```
Scaffold
 |_body: 
   |_SingleChildScrollView
     |_Column
       |_Container
       |_Container
       |_Continaer (400 height)
         |_ListView
       |_Container (Save Button)
```

##### Change it to :

```
Scaffold
 |_body: 
   |_SingleChildScrollView
     |_Column
       |_Container
       |_Container
       |_ListView
         |shrinkWrap:true
         |physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
 |_bottomNavigationBar
   |_Container (Save Button)
```

Comment: @Irfan I have added the code structure, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can add `shrinkWrap:true` in your `ListView.builder()` and add `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to it otherwise your list won't scroll.

Here's an example

```js
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> paybylist = [
      'A',
      'B',
      'C',
      'D',
      'E',
      'F',
      'G',
      'H',
      'I',
      'J',
      'K',
      'L',
      'M',
      'N',
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(child: Text('Container1')),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              //color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: TextField(),
              ),
            ),
            Text('Select Payment Mode'),
            Container(
              // height: 400,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: paybylist.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(paybylist[index]),
                    );
                  }),
            ),

//want to add available space between listview and save button

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Center(child: Text('Save')),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Also you can add your save button either in `Stack` or `BottomNavigationBar`, that way the button will be always visible.

Comment: Yes it worked but not getting exactly what I wanted..looks like need to change view...